# How to define width to Twitter tweets with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I made a script that let me embed Twitter tweets through their URL's but I have a problem which is I can't define a custom width to the tweet.

This is the HTML code :

```
<span id="tweet-link">https://twitter.com/robdelaney/status/329651129988288514</span>
```

This is the JQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = $("#tweet-link").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url="+url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            $('#tweet-link').html(data.html);
        }
    });
})
```

I tried to change the width through this code but it didn't work for me.

```
data.width = 800;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to set width in the wrong place.  You'd want to do something more like this:

```
$('#tweet-link').css('width', 800);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Matios, may I ask if you're referring to the rendered tweet's width itself? If so, then perhaps the API documentation on Twitter's website can be of further use; specifically the "maxwidth" attribute which can be added to your ajax call

Twitter's API: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed

maxwidth definition:

"The maximum width of a rendered Tweet in whole pixels. This value must be between 220 and 550 inclusive. A supplied value under or over the allowed range will be returned as the minimum or maximum supported width respectively; the reset width value will be reflected in the returned width property."